# How can I validate mobile number using Regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex

Recently I'm working in a project, in which I need validate some mobile numbers according to mobile operator's codes. Here some examples:

> 01100000000
>   01500000000
>   01700000000
>   01800000000
>   01900000000

Now I want to validate, first 3 digits must be in (011,015,017,018,019) and next 8 characters must be digit and if user enter something like 0120000000 then the match will be false, cause
valid operator code should be in (011,015,017,018,019).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't forget to add anchors in the regex while doing validations.

```
@"^(011|015|017|018|019)\d{8}$"
```

Reduced one,

```
@"^(01[15789])\d{8}$"
```

`^` Asserts that we are at the start and `$` asserts that we are at the end. `\d{8}` matches exactly 8 digits.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rX5eE5/6)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do it without using regular expressions

```
string[] operatorCodes = new[] {"011", "015", "017", "018", "019"};

string number = "01100000000";

if (number.Length == 11 
    && number.All(char.IsDigit)
    && operatorCodes.Any(number.StartsWith))
{
    // Valid mobile number.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can group symbols in a regex with `()`, and use `|` for "or", thus

```
(011|015|017|018|019)[0-9]{8}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following mobile number pattern:

**Sample:**

```
Regex.IsMatch("989373286128", @"^((((\+989)|(00989))|(09)|(989))(10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|30|31|32|33|34|35|36|37|38|39|90))(\d{7})$")
```

**Test:**

```
+989103286128   -> Success
00989103286128  -> Success
989103286128    -> Success
+989773286128   -> Fail
009891032861282 -> Fail
```

**GitHub:**

[ValidateMobileNumber](https://github.com/omidnasri/ValidateMobileNumber/tree/master)

I hope this help you.